# Trouble Specifying Handler for Api Gateway in AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I've been following a Udemy course on AWS CDK and I'm trying to create a lambda function and associate it to my api gateway integration.  I have the following code:

```
    const getPhotos = new lambda.NodejsFunction(this, "MySimpleAppLambda", {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      entry: path.join(__dirname, "..", "api", "get-photos", "index.ts"),
      handler: "getPhotos",
      environment: {
        PHOTO_BUCKET_NAME: bucket.bucketName
      }
    });

    // create lambda integration with api gateway
    const lambdaIntegration = new LambdaProxyIntegration({
      handler: getPhotos
    });
```

Unfortunately the handler property of LambdaProxyIntegration requires an instance of IFunction which lambda.NodejsFunction does not appear to support.  What's the best way to adjust to pass in the correct reference to LambdaProxyIntegration?

Answer (score 0):

`NodejsFunction` extends `Function` which implements `IFunction`.

so, we can pass object `NodejsFunction` directly to handler.

```
const lambdaIntegration = new LambdaProxyIntegration({
  handler: getPhotos
});
```